# Cross-Reference with external file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In attempting to create a cross-reference to an external xml file to replace values found in the original xml with an xslt, I ran into an issue where nothing was being returned.

This is the external document titled "codes.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <codes>
    <paymentmethodcode>
      <code id="CHK" desc="Check"/>
      <code id="ACH" desc="Automated Clearing House" />
      <code id="BOP" desc="Financial Institution Option" />
      <code id="FWT" desc="Federal Reserve Funds" />
      <code id="NON" desc="Non Payment Data" />
    </paymentmethodcode>
  </codes>
```

This is the top of the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />      

<xsl:param name="lookup" select="'codes.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="lookupDoc" select="document($lookup)" />
<xsl:key name='paymentmethodcode' match='lu:codes/paymentmethodcode/code' use='@id' />
```

Within the template I attempted to retrieve the 'desc' attribute of the code, but nothing was returned until the "normalize-space()" function was applied:

```
 <xsl:template match ="FunctionGroup/Transaction"> 

        <div class="infoLeft">
          <p><label>Filename:</label></p>


          <p><label>Pay Method:</label>

          <xsl:variable name="paymethodvalue" select="normalize-space(BPR/BPR04)" />

          <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
               <xsl:variable name="value" select="key('paymentmethodcode', $paymethodvalue)" />
               <xsl:value-of select="$value/@desc"/>
          </xsl:for-each></p>


      </div>
   </xsl:template>
```

The rest:

```
<xsl:template match="*">

   <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <title>EDI</title>
     </head>
     <body>                   
       <xsl:apply-templates select="FunctionGroup/Transaction" />     
     </body>
    </html>

 </xsl:template>
```

Here is a minimized version of the input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <FunctionGroup>
  <Transaction>
    <BPR>
     <BPR04>
       CHK
     </BPR04>
    </BPR>
  </Transaction>
 </FunctionGroup>
```

Comment: If you provide more information (source XML, full XSLT code), it is more likely that someone can help you.

Comment: Where is the `lu:` prefix defined (and why is it needed at all)?

Comment: Sure, otherwise you could not run it. But can you _show_ its definition (together with the rest of the code)? P.S. Please edit your post, do not include code in comments.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. Also make sure we can reproduce your problem using your code. There is no `lu:codes` parent node in the 'codes.xml' document you have posted here.

Comment: Finally! See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Now we're getting closer it seems. There are trailing whitespaces in the text content of `BPR04`. Use `<xsl:variable name="paymethodvalue" select="normalize-space(BPR/BPR04)" />` as the variable definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't see your input XML, so we don't know if the template matches anything. I suggest you try the following test stylesheet (with any input):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup" select="'codes.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="lookupDoc" select="document($lookup)" />
<xsl:key name="paymentmethodcode" match="code" use='@id' />   

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('paymentmethodcode', 'CHK')/@desc"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which should return;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>Check</result>
```

Note that it's not necessary to reference the lu: prefix or its associated namespace.

---

### Edit:

Change:

```
<xsl:variable name="paymethodvalue" select="BPR/BPR04" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="paymethodvalue" select="normalize-space(BPR/BPR04)" />
```

Or apply the the normalize-space() function when calling the key() function, i.e.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('paymentmethodcode', normalize-space($paymethodvalue))/@desc"/>
```

Comment: Exactly. Would +1 if I hadn't already. @AaronSchäfer I hope you've learned your lesson now. If you'd provided the source XML right at the start, it would have been less painstaking.

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc/paymentmethodcode/code"` looks wrong based on your `match`, I think you only need `xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc"` to change the context to the external document for the `key` based lookup. If that change does not suffice to make it work then show us all details of namespaces used in the input XML, the XSLT and the lookup document.

I tried to reproduce the problem with your snippets, XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:lu="http://example.com/lookup">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />      

<xsl:param name="lookup" select="'test2014081201.xml'" />
<xsl:variable name="lookupDoc" select="document($lookup)" />
<xsl:key name='paymentmethodcode' match='lu:codes/paymentmethodcode/code' use='@id' />      

<xsl:template match ="FunctionGroup/Transaction"> 

        <div class="infoLeft">
          <p><label>Filename:</label></p>


          <p><label>Pay Method:</label>

          <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
               <xsl:variable name="value" select="key('paymentmethodcode', 'CHK')" />
               <xsl:value-of select="$value/@desc"/>
          </xsl:for-each></p>


      </div>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML input is simply

```
<FunctionGroup>
  <Transaction>foo</Transaction>
</FunctionGroup>
```

the lookup document is as posted and then Saxon 6.5 gives the result

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<div xmlns:lu="http://example.com/lookup" class="infoLeft">
   <p><label>Filename:</label></p>
   <p><label>Pay Method:</label>Check
   </p>
</div>
```

so the "Check" value was found.

Comment: I have edited and tried to incorporate your snippets into a minimal but complete example, the lookup works for me. So we need to see a complete sample and get information on the XSLT processor you use.

Comment: @AaronSchäfer Could it be that you are trying to use a variable outside its scope? Or else, did you put the variable value between quotes or not? (Pure guesswork, without seeing this particular piece of code)

Comment: Make sure that the variable _value_ is in quotes: `<xsl:variable name="str" select="'CHK'"/>`, but in `xsl:key` where you use the variable, there must not be quotes; simply `$str`, _NOT_ `'$str'` as the argument.

Comment: @AaronSchäfer "*variables are not allowed as patterns in xsl 1.0.*" What does this have to do with calling the key() function? -- If there is one thing you should have learned in the last hour, it is this: do not describe your code; show it.

Comment: @AaronSchäfer This is useless if we don't see your input XML (preferably a minimized example that contains only FunctionGroup/Transaction/BPR/BPR04 and their ancestors).